# Evaluating integrals in Python 3.7; strange behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, math, integral

I written some code to approximate an integral: [image] using Python 3.7, but some strange behaviour is happening which is giving me the wrong result. I derived the formula in the following way:

Let [image] then [image] and [image] for n = 1,2,3...

This implemented in my code:

```
import numpy as np

I = 1
for n in range(1,21):
    I = 2*(np.log(2))**n - n*I
```

This should result in I = 0.0000419426270488826, but my code is giving me 50.40429353428721. I've been trying to figure out what is happing using print statements:

```
print("Iteration: ",n)
print("first half: ",2*(np.log(2))**n)
print("second half: ", n*I)
print("New I: ",I, "\n")
```

You can see that the second half of the equation turns negative in iteration 17, but I don't understand why, since both I and n should be positive. My guess is that this is where the problems start to occur. Does anyone know why the result is incorrect, and if my assumption is correct? I'm using Mac OS X el Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: Looks like `n*I` is greater than `2*(np.log(2))**n` after `n >= 17`. That will make `I` negative.

Comment: That should not be the case. The I from iteration 16 should be used when calculating the new I in iteration 17. The I in itteration 16 is 0.0006564050553949539. This times 17 should give a positive number.

Comment: From your code `I = 2*(np.log(2))**n - n*I`. Even if `n*I` is a positive integer, if it is greater than `2*(np.log(2))**n`, that will result in a negative number.

Comment: I understand that a positive number minus a larger positive number will give me a negative number. But that does not explain why a positive number times a positive number gives me a negative number in python.

Comment: Um... Where do you see a positive number times a positive number equals a negative? Maybe this spreadsheet will help: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Xha.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because of the overflow error.
If you increase the float accuracy by using [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), it will solve the problem. 
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import *
getcontext()

n = 20
print('n=',n)
def In(n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2*Decimal(2).ln()**n - n*In(n-1)

print('I{}={}'.format(n,float(In(n))))

# check with an existing function of Scipy
import scipy.integrate as integrate
result = integrate.quad(lambda x: np.log(x)**n, 1, 2)
print('I{}={}'.format(n,result))
```

Here is the output:

```
n= 20
I20=4.1942535120159466e-05
I20=(4.1942627048882645e-05, 7.29235597161084e-18)
```

By the way, the formula needs to be corrected by replacing `ln(x)` with `ln(2)`.

Updated: Probably the name of the problem is [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance)

Comment: That does seem to do the trick, thank you! I have one small question: Why is this called an overflow error? Isn't overflow when a number is too large to represent with the current precision? I thought that the problem might be loss of significance, since two small numbers are being subtracted with finite precision. Iterating more and more would lead to more and more discrepancies in the values in Python.

Comment: Yep, I think you're right, I've updated the answer. Clearly, when the values are getting more and more small, subtracting two small number can remove significant digits. If this is repeated many times, it will lead to more discrepancies in the result.